# Problem with acquiring data from XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom, nullpointerexception

I've tried using DOM, Xpath and currently i've only succeeded with using streams to iterate through each line and get the data that way. Apparently my shelfNodeLists.getAttributes.getNamedItem produces it and I cannot see why it should do that. Couldn't find any relevant information on any current forums.

I'm really trying to get DOM to work since i've got tons of XML files to iterate through and i've heard it's efficient with much data.

Here is the NPE i'm getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Node.getTextContent()" because the return value of "org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap.getNamedItem(String)" is null
    at ReadXmlDomParser.main(ReadXmlDomParser.java:75)
```

Here is the code that produces the exception:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ReadXmlDomParser {

    private static final String FILENAME = "src/main/resources/TestXML.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Instantiate the Factory
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            // process XML
            dbf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

            // parse XML file
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new File(FILENAME));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root Element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            System.out.println("------");

            // get <Shelf>
            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("Shelf");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < list.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node node = list.item(temp);

                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element element = (Element) node;

                    // get shelf's attribute
                    String id = element.getAttribute("ShelfID");

                    // get text
                    String positionText = element.getElementsByTagName("Position").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String dangerLevelText = element.getElementsByTagName("DangerLevel").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String coffeeText = element.getElementsByTagName("Coffee").item(0).getTextContent();

                    NodeList shelfNodeList = element.getElementsByTagName("Position");
                    NodeList shelfNodeList1 = element.getElementsByTagName("DangerLevel");
                    NodeList shelfNodeList2 = element.getElementsByTagName("Coffee");

                    //get attributes
                    String position = shelfNodeList.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Position").getTextContent();
                    String dangerLevel = shelfNodeList1.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("DangerLevel").getTextContent();
                    String coffee = shelfNodeList2.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Coffee").getTextContent();


                    System.out.println("Current Element :" + node.getNodeName());
                    System.out.println("Player Id : " + id);
                    System.out.printf("Position : %,.2f [%s]%n%n", Float.parseFloat(positionText), position);
                    System.out.printf("DangerLevel [Stat] : %,.2f [%s]%n%n", Float.parseFloat(dangerLevelText), dangerLevel);
                    System.out.printf("Coffee [Stat] : %,.2f [%s]%n%n", Float.parseFloat(coffeeText), coffee);
                }
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And here is the XML file that i'm trying to extract data from:

```
<Section>
    <Shelf ShelfID="p60772">
        <Position BioChemicalID="Bio1523">1</Position>
        <Position BioChemicalID="Bio9612">4</Position>
        <DangerLevel scale="1-10"> 6</DangerLevel>
        <DangerLevel scale="1-10"> 2</DangerLevel>
        <Coffee java="Yes"> 100%</Coffee>
    </Shelf>
</Section>
```

Comment: In your section "get attributes" you should use the names of the attributes not of the elements. Instead of "...getNamedItem("Position")" use "...getNamedItem("BioChemicalID")".

Comment: ... and "100%" will not be parsed as a float because of the %.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why are you calling 'shelfNodeList.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Position")'? 'Position' is an element, not an attribute. It should be 'shelfNodeList.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()'. You should get '1' for the first Position element and '4' for the second

Comment: Thanks alot @Ironluca! I didn't notice that error. cheers!

Comment: @RalfRenz Oh I totally missed that and thanks for making me change my test value!